# Написание местоимений насчет их и насчет них

Tags: местоимения

Подскажите как правильно пишется насчет их или насчет них

Answer (score 2):

У Розенталя читаем: В русском языке  звук Н добавляется, если местоимение стоит после любого из простых, или первообразных, предлогов (без, в, для, до, за, из, к, на, над, о, от, по, под и др.), а также после многих наречных предлогов (возле, вокруг, впереди, мимо, напротив, около, после, посреди, сзади и некоторых других, употребляющихся с родительным падежом).

Однако такие предлоги, как внутри, вне,употребляются в основном без начального н. Не требуют после себя вставки н также сложные предлоги в сочетании с местоимением, например: в отношении его, при помощи ее, не в пример им, в противовес ему, по поводу ее, за исключением их, со стороны его, по причине ее; также: наподобие его, насчет их.

http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm

Так что вставки Н не требуется,но и не возбраняется произносить и писать с ней. Если нужна норма, например, в заданиях ЕГЭ,предпочтительнее будет писать по Розенталю: насчёт их.

Откуда взялось-Н-? В результате исторического развития языка. Первообразные предлоги в,с,к первоначально оканчивались на носовой согласный и имели вид вън, сън,кън(сън имъ, кън ему и т.д.).В дальнейшем в результате процесса переразложения конечный согласный предлога стал восприниматься как начальное Н местоимений. По аналогии с первообразными предлогами в,с,к начальное Н появилось и после предлогов у, возле, около и других. Однако после предлогов позднейшего образования (благодаря, вопреки, навстречу и др.) Н в местоимениях не употребляется: возле него, но навстречу ему. Правда, в последнее время всё чаще действует закон аналогии и такие написания с Н, если произносится нормально,встречаются, но это ненормативно, допускается как разговорное.

Comment: А как вы объясните следующее: 1) почему добавление Н коснулось только местоимений; 2) создается впечатление, что решение различно для  родительного и дательного падежа, а не для ранних и поздних предлогов.

Comment: И.-он, Р.-его( от него, но вне его, внутри его),Д.-ему(к нему,вопреки ему, наперекор ему),В.-его(на него,внутрь его, включая его),Т.-им (с ним,кончая им-" работал начиная с мая и кончая им"),П.-о нём,что-то не найду производного предлога с предложным падежом. Эвфористические вставки есть и в других частях речи, например, вынимать - из "имать"и др.

Comment: Если хотите дальше разбираться-разбирайтесь: 
http://orthowiki.kalan.cc/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD
у меня нет времени и желания копаться в том, что и так понятно. Исторической грамматики под рукой нет, ищите в Интернете историю развития местоимений.

Comment: София, любите Вы проводить изыскания, из всего делать проблему, выдвигать гипотезы,пытаться их доказать - проводить исследования.Деятельность исследовательского института, которая и идёт в научных кругах, это их профессия. Я предпочитаю воспользоваться уже добытыми знаниями профессионалов, при разных взглядах на проблему принимаю чью-то сторону, но таких вопросов не так много.По этому вопросу в науке разногласий нет.Зачем выискивать опровержения? Автор вопроса спросил,как правильно - ответьте ему, высказав своё мнение или чьё-то, но со ссылкой на него, а не просто на Интернет.И всё.

Comment: Судя по вашему основному ответу, надставка Н связана с нормированием речи, а нормы меняются, и хотелось бы ознакомиться с ними по современным  источникам, а не по справочнику для редакторов из прошлого века. Проводить изыскания я не люблю, потому что неблагодарное это дело, но еще больше не люблю учить странички наизусть.

Comment: Да никто и не заставляет учить наизусть, ради бога,надо понимать.И здесь всё понятно: что пришло из истории - традиция, нужно писать так же(и говорить), а что образовано в наши дни-как случилось в языке, нужно смотреть в словарях. У нас действует закон аналогий(аналогично с историческими образованиями)и новые законы словообразования, так что никакие изыскания не помогут - так сложилось в языке.

Comment: Никто не может установить засчёт них или засчёт их, можно только посоветовать:после простых предлогов - как положено по традиции - с Н, а остальные факультативно, как удобно. Не надо придумывать. Я о фразе "Получается, что правильно: НАСЧЕТ НИХ". И Розенталь не говорит, что НАДО, он говорит ОБЫЧНО НЕ ТРЕБУЕТСЯ, а не правильно-неправильно.

Comment: Чтобы Вас не расстраивать и не отвлекать от сути проблемы, я убрала фразу из ответа. А вот по поводу общей факультативности всех производных предлогов не получится, некоторые из них явно требуют  "Н", а факультативной является только небольшая группа предлогов. К примеру, я бы не стала  допускать варианты для "вместо него" и "благодаря ему".

Answer (score 1):

Из грамматики-80

Вариант 1. Существуют притяжательные несклоняемые местоимения ЕГО, ЕЕ, ИХ, в этом случае правильно: НАСЧЕТ ИХ ПЛАНОВ.

Вариант 2. Приводятся падежные формы личных местоимений: ОНИ, ИХ (Р.п.), ИМ, ИМИ, О НИХ.
Но дополнительно сообщается следующая информация:при объединении с предлогом формы косвенных падежей  образуют так называемые припредложные формы без (J), но с начальным Н: от него, с ним, между ними. Конкретной информации по поводу предлога НАСЧЕТ нет, в Интернете можно встретить обе формы.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Российский свободолюбивый народ на просторах Интернета не слишком уважает науку орфографию. Оно и понятно – там никогда и ничего не объясняют, но откуда-то сверху предлагают готовые   циркуляры в виде руководства для пользователей. Вот и сейчас  я гляжу на страничку из Розенталя, где следует перечень правил употребления  надставки «Н». Что это: грамматика, орфография, орфоэпия? Если материал отражает нормы произношения, то от какого он года, тридцатилетней давности?

По поводу предлога НАСЧЕТ Розенталь выражается однозначно: надо говорить «насчет их».  Как быть грамотным по Розенталю? Да очень просто, варианты разные. Можете на досуге ознакомиться с основами исторической грамматики или выучить наизусть предлагаемую страничку. Будете говорить «насчет них, то есть насчет их».

А  может быть, не так всё и сложно? В конце концов, для всех ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНЫХ предлогов картина ясная: как и в случае предложного падежа, во всех остальных падежах при наличии предлога надставка «Н» обязательна (это историческая традиция): без него, для них, между ними. Это же правило действует и для составных предлогов (также после ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНОГО  предлога):  в отличие от него, по сравнению с ним.

Не всё ясно  относительно ПРОИЗВОДНЫХ предлогов, образованных от наречий, существительных, деепричастий. Соблюдается ли там историческая традиция, да и почему она должна соблюдаться?  Например, мы все говорим: благодарить его – благодаря ему, но, с другой стороны, вы же не скажете «вместо его». Следовательно, на выбор «Н» влияют какие-то ФАКТОРЫ, и можно попробовать их назвать. Будем считать, что это вид производного предлога и  падеж, которым он управляет.

Практически большинство всех предлогов с «Н» управляют РОДИТЕЛЬНЫМ ПАДЕЖОМ  - в этом случае НЕОБХОДИМО РАЗЛИЧИТЬ следующие варианты: мимо их дома (притяж.мест.) – мимо них (личное мест.). НАРЕЧНЫЕ предлоги  близки к непроизводным  предлогам, поэтому они в большей степени склонны к «Н», что нельзя сказать о предлогах, мотивированных существительными.

И теперь о предлоге НАСЧЕТ. Практически  встречаются обе формы (насчет их/них), здесь действуют противоположные факторы: предлог образован на основе существительного, но управляет Р.п. Вообще говоря,  не все  производные предлоги  часто управляют местоимениями, а частотность употребления также влияет на изменение нормы. Соответственно, мы имеем НЕУСТОЙЧИВОЕ положение для предлога  «насчет», в то время как предлог «вместо», управляющий Р.п., четко определил свои позиции.

Comment: София, Интернет - "гигантская помойка", где можно найти всё - от мнения алкаша Васи до мнения академика. Вы не согласны с Розенталем? Он говорит неправильно?

Comment: И желательно ссылочку увидеть, что правильно в Г-80  НАСЧЁТ НИХ, а НАСЧЁТ ИХ-неправильно.

Comment: В Интернете я просто наблюдаю реальную частоту употребления различных слов. В Г-80 конкретно по поводу "насчет их/них" нет информации, поэтому ничего однозначно утверждать не могу. Розенталь мне очень нравится - жаль только, что он никак не объясняет свое понимание данной темы. Есть ли еще какие-нибудь серьезные источники на эту тему, или все только Розенталя переписывают? Это связано с грамматикой или фонетикой, какова история вопроса, меняется или не меняется норма? Вот что хотелось бы понять, а не только то, как отвечать на ЕГЭ.

Comment: http://rushkolnik.ru/docs/87/index-183859-13.html
§ 1282 - Вы немного не дочитали:
 Формы предл. п. ед. и мн. ч., не употребляющиеся без предлога, всегда имеют в начале основы |н'|-: /о//нем/, /при/ /ней/, /в/ /них/. ИХ- вполне употребляется , а вот при простых предлогах без Н не употребляются, однако у нас сложный предлог насчёт.

Comment: Много писать, добавлю в ответ. А Розенталь и не обязан переписывать историческую грамматику,это её дело объяснять такие написания. И ещё...Не обижайтесь на меня и если что, простите. Сегодня Прощёный день.Никого обидеть не хочу. Прошу у всех прощенья за вольные и невольные обиды.Видит Бог, желаю всем только добра...

Comment: Людмила, позвольте присоединиться к Вашим словам! Простите меня, форумчане, и не держите на меня зла...

Comment: И на меня некоторые форумчане обижались. Простите меня, пожалуйста, я буду исправляться. Мне очень по душе  следующие слова: "Люди не соперники ваши, а ваши братья и сестры". Иногда приходится напоминать их себе.